# MySQL SELECT and AVG()

Tags: php

I have 2 tables:

Schedule

```
id  id_teacher       subject    class     hour    day
1   2 [->]             Math         X C     8   Monday
2   2 [->]             Math         X C     12  Wednesday
3   2 [->]             Math         X C     9   Tuesday
4   2 [->]             Math         VI B    10  Monday
5   2 [->]             Math         X C     11  Monday
6   2 [->]             Math         X C     10  Tuesday
7   5 [->]             Chemistry    X C     9   Monday
8   5 [->]             Chemistry    X C     12  Monday
9   2 [->]             Sports       X C     7   Monday
10  5 [->]             Biology      X C     11  Friday
11  2 [->]             English      X C     12  Friday
12  2 [->]             Chemistry    X C     9   Thursday
```

Grades

```
Id  id_elev     subject     date        grade   semester
4   1 [->]      English     2013-10-01  8       1
5   1 [->]      Math        2013-10-03  7       1
6   1 [->]      Math        2012-10-03  8       2
7   1 [->]      English     2013-02-28  9       2
8   4 [->]      Math        2013-10-06  5       1
9   4 [->]      English     2013-07-02  7       2
10  4 [->]      Sport       2013-10-01  9       1
11  1 [->]      Math        2013-10-03  4       1
12  1 [->]      English     2013-10-16  9       1
```

I want to take all subjects from Schedule:

Biology, Chemistry, English, Math, Sports

```
$sth1 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE class = :class GROUP BY subject;");
$sth1->bindParam(":class", $a);   
$sth1->execute();
while($result1 = $sth1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     echo $result1['subject']." ";
}
```

$a is a variable equal with 'X C'.

Till now everything is ok.

Now I want to select all subjects and the average of every subject.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id_student, subject, AVG(grade) FROM grades WHERE id_student = :id_student AND semester = 2 GROUP BY subject;");
$sth->bindParam(":id_student", $_SESSION['id']);   
$sth->execute();

while($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo $result['subject']." ".$result['AVG(grade)'];
}
```

And it shows me:

English 9.0000 Math 8.0000

But I want to select all subjects from schedule and make the agerage even if the student doesn't have any grade at that subject ... If it doesn't echo 0.

I'm trying to make a graph with subjects and grades of every student.
The picture probably will show exactly what I want.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: That is because the student does not have Biology or Chemistry in his second semester. Your existing logic is right than from what you are expecting.

Comment: Do you have a separate table of subjects, like in a properly normalized database?

Comment: You need inner joint query for it

Comment: No . I only have those 2 tables and only use them ... I can't make a new table.

The student has Biology and Chemistry in both semesters ... he doesn't have grades at those subjects.

Comment: I used Inner Join but the problem is that I didn't knew how to use it properly because it didn't show me anything.

Comment: Something like `SELECT g.id_student, 
       s.subject, 
       AVG(g.grade) 
  FROM grades g
  INNER JOIN schedule s
          ON s.subject = g.subject
 WHERE g.id_student = :id_student 
   AND g.semester = 2 
 GROUP BY s.subject`?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it:

```
$a = 'X C';
$sth1 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE class = :class GROUP BY subject;");
        $sth1->bindParam(":class", $a);   
        $sth1->execute();
        while($result1 = $sth1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id_student, subject, AVG(grade) FROM grades WHERE id_student = :id_student AND subject = :subject AND semester = 2;");
            $sth->bindParam(":id_student", $_SESSION['id']);   
            $sth->bindParam(":subject", $result1['subject']);   
            $sth->execute();
            $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            echo $result1['subject']." ";
            if (is_null($result['AVG(grade)'])) {
            // do stuff
            }else{
            // do stuff
            }
```

Comment: You've solved it inefficiently - try to learn to use JOINs in SQL statements, and your code will be so much simpler and faster